# Importing files in __init__.py

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I'm trying to use a piece of code I got from somewhere. The code has a structure equivalent to this:

```
project/
   test.py
   somepackage/
      __init__.py
      file1.py
      file2.py
```

`__init__.py` contains only:

```
from file1 import *
from file2 import *
```

while in `test.py` I have

```
from somepackage import *
```

Running `test.py` gives an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'somepackage' has no attribute 'file1'
```

I'm using python version 3.5 if that matters

Comment: Use a relative import: `from .file import *`

Comment: Also see [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'm a bit puzzled, though, by the fact that this was a piece of code made by someone else available on github. I would think that the person has at least tested that the imports in the code work.